# Converting a basic CURL to Python's request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

The following `curl` works fine:

```
curl -d '{"date":"2015-05-27T03:48:29.002Z"}' http://blabla.com
```

but I can't get it to work with `requests`:

```
payload = {'date' : '2015-05-27T03:48:29.002Z'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=h)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With curl you are posting *JSON* data, while the `params` argument sets *URL query parameters* (whatever comes after the `?` in the URL).

Use the `json` keyword argument, and the correct verb (`-d` tells `curl` to use a POST request):

```
payload = {'date' : '2015-05-27T03:48:29.002Z'}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

This will, in addition, set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Comment: Ha! the problem was exactly that I was using `get` instead of `post`; I should've RTFM for curl :) Accepted for the extra explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on all `requests` versions:

```
payload = {'date' : '2015-05-27T03:48:29.002Z'}
r = requests.post('http://blabla.com', data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `post` instead `get`:

```
payload = {'date' : '2015-05-27T03:48:29.002Z'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=h)
```